# SWRevealViewcontroller Code Query for implementing navigation controller Bar Button

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to implement the bar button with SWreveal ViewController and instead of implementing the slider button "Open" For all views.I made one base class BaseController and from that I inherited the viewcontroller for which i wish to have slider but my below code works for the pan gesture but code 2 doesn't not for the button.Can Someone tell me why?

Code1:(Working Code)

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Sider", style: .done, target: self, action: nil )         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target = self.revealViewController()         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

Code2:(Not Working)

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Sider", style: .done, target: self, action: Selector("revealToggle:") )
```

Code1 works but Code2 doesn't work Can someone tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Code2** check `Selector("revealToggle:")` is not your class method so you have to select `target: SWrevealViewController` in code2

You can write code2 like below:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Sider", style: .done, target: self.revealViewController(), action: Selector("revealToggle:") )
```